# MySQL динамическое формирование условий выборки

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите как реализовать такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE $a $c $f $h $y $z $x
```

Переменные содержат примерно следующее `$а = "AND new LIKE \"%$new%\"";` и тд.

Соответственно `WHERE AND` это ошибка. И любая из переменных `$a $c $f $h $y $z $x` может отсутствовать вообще, то есть например подставить после `WHERE` содержимое какой нибудь переменной без `AND` а дальше все остальные `$a $c $f $h $y $z $x` не получиться.

Надеюсь поймете мою писанину ))) спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введите новую переменную и поставьте её первой после `WHERE`:

```
$ruSO = "1=1";
```

Тогда ваш запрос превратиться в:

```
SELECT *
FROM db
WHERE 1=1
    and new like ...
```

Comment: Если все формируемые условия объединяются с использованием оператора AND, достаточно просто единички: `SELECT * FROM db WHERE 1 $a $c $f $h $y $z $x`